# In R: add rows based on a date and another condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("john","mary","tom"),dates=c(as.Date("2010-06-01"),as.Date("2010-07-09"),as.Date("2010-06-01")),tours_missed=c(2,12,6))

names   dates       tours_missed
john    2010-06-01  2
mary    2010-07-09  12
tom     2010-06-01  6
```

I want to be able to add a row with the dates the person missed. There are 2 tours every day the person works. Each person works every 4 days.

The result should be (though the order doesn't matter):

```
names   dates       tours_missed
john    2010-06-01  2
mary    2010-07-09  12
mary    2010-07-13  12
mary    2010-07-17  12
mary    2010-07-21  12
mary    2010-07-25  12
mary    2010-07-29  12
tom     2010-06-01  6
tom     2010-06-05  6
tom     2010-06-09  6
```

I have already tried looking at these topics but was unable to produce the above result: [Add rows to a data frame based on date in previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838210/add-rows-to-a-data-frame-based-on-date-in-previous-row), [In R: Add rows with data of previous row to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487290/in-r-add-rows-with-data-of-previous-row-to-data-frame), [add new row to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048660/make-new-column-which-adds-30-days-to-date-on-every-row-r). Thanks for your help!

Comment: as is, I can't see how one would go from `df` to the desired answer. is there anything in `df` that tells us that mary should appear 6 times, and john only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or convert in-place using setDT

# all of the relevant dates
dates.all = dt[, seq(dates, length = tours_missed/2, by = "4 days"), by = names]

# set the key and merge filling in the blanks with previous observation
setkey(dt, names, dates)
dt[dates.all, roll = T]
#    names      dates tours_missed
# 1:  john 2010-06-01            2
# 2:  mary 2010-07-09           12
# 3:  mary 2010-07-13           12
# 4:  mary 2010-07-17           12
# 5:  mary 2010-07-21           12
# 6:  mary 2010-07-25           12
# 7:  mary 2010-07-29           12
# 8:   tom 2010-06-01            6
# 9:   tom 2010-06-05            6
#10:   tom 2010-06-09            6
```

Or if merging is unnecessary (not quite clear from OP), just construct the answer:

```
dt[, list(dates = seq(dates, length = tours_missed/2, by = "4 days"), tours_missed)
   , by = names]
```